# How to wrap a div vertically only?

Tags: html, css

As the title says, I want to wrap a div vertically around an image, but I want the width to remain fluid and changeable:

```
|_________________|
|     |XXXXXX|    |
|     |XXXXXX|    |
|     |XXXXXX|    |
|     |XXXXXX|    |
|     |XXXXXX|    |
|     |XXXXXX|    |
|-----------------|
```

Where the box is the container and the content is the block of characters. The bottom and top sides should meet with the content block, I want the content to center (margin: 0 auto;).

Comment: I don't understand. Is the container 100% width, or do you just want some pixels of padding on each side of the image (the 'X'-es)

Comment: I'm not keen on hacking the size of the div. Really I'm looking for a single CSS rule to wrap a div on the top and bottom without affecting the distance of the sides. Using position: absolute; and then using top: 0; bottom: 0; is inconvenient sometimes because of other positioning rules, so I'm looking for any variation except for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/As3bP/1/)

Try resize the output section in the fiddle and you will see that the content will always be in the center.

Here's the CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #CCC;
}

.inner {
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect - definitely the least invasive way in terms of how it affects positioning of the parent div. I will mark this as the answer in 6 minutes, thank you!